# Problemas a cobrar tarjeta de crédito con mercadopago api!

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, mercadopago, mercadolibre

Saludos,

Estoy tratando de hacer un cobro con tarjeta como en mi servidor `node.js` siguiendo el ejemplo de la documentación:

```
var MP = require ("mercadopago");

var mp = new MP ("ACCESS_TOKEN");

    var doPayment = mp.post ("/v1/payments", {
  "binary_mode": true,
  "transaction_amount": "5250.35",
  "token": "5368dc34b10d78d7f4f5eb55598f6243",
  "description": "Compra de un cafe",
  "installments": 1,
  "payer": {
    "identification": {
      "type": "CI-V",
      "number": "12345678"
    },
    "entity_type": "individual",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "type": "guest",
    "phone": {
      "area_code": "0212",
      "number": "1110778"
    },
    "first_name": "APROPEDRO PEREZ",
    "last_name": "APROPEDRO PEREZ"
  },
  "payment_method_id": "master-card",
  "statement_descriptor": "Quicpy Pago"
});

doPayment.then (
    function (payment) {
        console.log (payment);
    },
    function (error){
        console.log (error);
    });
```

Pero no me funciona siempre me da el mismo error:

> {\"message\":\"Params Error\",\"error\":\"bad_request\",\"status\":400,\"cause\":{\"code\":1,\"description\":\"Params Error\",\"data\":null}}

Alguien me puede indicar cuáles son los parámetros obligatorios para el cobro con tarjeta de crédito, o cual es el error que esta presentado mi codigo

gracias

Answer (score -1):

Los parametros mínimos para un cobro con tarjeta son:

```
{
        "transaction_amount": 100,
        "token": "CARD_TOKEN",
        "description": "Title of what you are paying for",
        "installments": 1,
        "payment_method_id": "visa",
        "payer": {
            "email": "test_user_19653727@testuser.com"
        }
    }
```

Y este seria un request completo

```
{
    "transaction_amount": 100,
    "token": "ff8080814c11e237014c1ff593b57b4d",
    "description": "Title of what you are paying for",
    "installments": 12,
    "payment_method_id": "visa",
    "payer": {
        "email": "test_user_19653727@testuser.com"
    },
    "external_reference": "Reference_1234",
    "metadata": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    },
    "statement_descriptor": "MY E-STORE",
    "notification_url": "https://www.your-site.com/webhooks",
    "additional_info": {
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "item-ID-1234",
                "title": "Title of what you are paying for",
                "picture_url": "https://www.mercadopago.com/org-img/MP3/home/logomp3.gif",
                "description": "Item description",
                "category_id": "art", // Available categories at https://api.mercadopago.com/item_categories
                "quantity": 1,
                "unit_price": 100
            }
        ],
        "payer": {
            "first_name": "user-name",
            "last_name": "user-surname",
            "registration_date": "2015-06-02T12:58:41.425-04:00",
            "phone": {
                "area_code": "11",
                "number": "4444-4444"
            },
            "address": {
                "street_name": "Street",
                "street_number": 123,
                "zip_code": "5700"
            } 
        },
        "shipments": {
            "receiver_address": {
                "zip_code": "5700",
                "street_name": "Street",
                "street_number": 123,
                "floor": 4,
                "apartment": "C"
            }
        }
    }
}
```